# Is there a specific way to name nodes in a Dataset on Python 3

Tags: python, range, networkx

Hi I am trying to build a graph of a .net dataset using Networkx(Python 3). My dataset consists a total of 40 nodes. I want to label the nodes(from 0 to 39). I have tried using xrange but unable to do so. Are there any specific methods to perform such a task?
Thank you.

I am sharing my code.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp

G = nx.read_pajek('E:/Data_sets/football.net')
F = nx.DiGraph(G)

G.add_node(0)
Demands = list(xrange(0 , 5000))
for i in xrange(5000):
   G.add_node(Demands[i])
   
print(nx.info(G))

nx.draw(F)
plt.show()
```

The code does not lable the nodes at all.

Comment: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/auto_examples/drawing/plot_labels_and_colors.html

Comment: First, it seems that you are using Python-2.7 which is no longer supported; stop using it immediately for your own sake. Second, your code shows 5000 nodes, not 40. So, which is true? Finally, `nx.draw(F)` does not draw node labels by default. Perhaps it's the drawing that confuses you? Use `nx.draw_networkx(F)` instead.

Comment: I was trying different methods to make the nodes number appear on my Output. I had a dataset initially of 4539 nodes. I tried to use the range function to provide a list of integers that python could use to number the nodes. I got frustrated after a while and willingly tried to run xrange on python 3. Which was just frustration. "nx.draw_networkx" certainly did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [`convert_node_labels_to_integers`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers.html#convert-node-labels-to-integers) will do what you're trying to do.  If you need the labels in a specific order based on the input data, the [`relabel_nodes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html#relabel-nodes) method will allow you to pass in a dictionary to match up new labels with existing labels.

You also need to pass `with_labels = True` when you use `nx.draw` in order to actually show the labels on the nodes when the graph is plotted.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!
Found it to be more efficient in achieving what I was looking for.